# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to t} \frac{x^2-x-\sqrt{x}+1}{-x^2+x-\sqrt{x}+1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$f(t)=\lim_{x\to t}{\frac{x^2-x-\sqrt{x}+1}{-x^2+x-\sqrt{x}+1}}, \quad t=1,+\infty$$

After drawing a graph, it appears that,  $f(1) = - \frac{1}{3} , f(\infty)=-1.$

But I don't know why this is happening. Give me a hint so I can solve the problem.

I'd appreciate it then.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with l'hopital

$\lim\limits_{x\to 1}  \frac{x^2-x-\sqrt{x}+1}{-x^2+x-\sqrt{x}+1}=  \lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{2x-1-\frac 1{2\sqrt{x}}}{-2x+1-\frac 1{2\sqrt{x}}}=\frac {1-\frac 12}{-1-\frac 12}=-\frac 13$

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}  \frac{x^2-x-\sqrt{x}+1}{-x^2+x-\sqrt{x}+1}=  \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{2x-1-\frac 1{2\sqrt{x}}}{-2x+1-\frac 1{2\sqrt{x}}}=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{2+\frac {\frac 2{\sqrt{x}}}{4x}}{-2+\frac {\frac 2{\sqrt{x}}}{4x}}=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{4x\sqrt{x}+ {1}}{-4x\sqrt{x}+1}=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{d(4x\sqrt{x})}{dx}}{-\frac{d(4x\sqrt{x})}{dx}}=-1$

Answer (score 1):

For finite limits $x\to 1$ for example, factoring is usually helpful,

$$\frac{x^2-x-\sqrt{x}+1}{-x^2+x-\sqrt{x}+1}=-
\frac{(\sqrt{x}-1)(x\sqrt{x}+x-1)}{(\sqrt{x}-1)(x\sqrt{x}+x+1)}$$
$$=-
\frac{x\sqrt{x}+x-1}{x\sqrt{x}+x+1}\to -\frac{1}{3}$$

For limits to $\infty$ divide top and bottom by the highest power, in this case $x^2$.

Comment: Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the limit at t=1, [L'Hospital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) is directly applicable

$$f(t)=\lim_{x\to 1}{\frac{x^2-x-\sqrt{x}+1}{-x^2+x-\sqrt{x}+1}}$$
        $$=\lim_{x\to 1}{\frac{2x-1-{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}}}{-2x+1-{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}}}}\to-\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: thank you for your hlep~